# Mocking InnerHTML output text Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, mocking, getelementbyid

I'm doing a project currently where we build a web app and only using vanilla javascript. We have been challenged to write our own testing framework and then use it for testing the app.

I am trying to test my controller so that it outputs the correct InnerHTML text to my id tag.

In doing this, I am using mocking to isolate this test. I am mocking my constructor parameters, as well as creating a custom tag and id, but my console.logs doesn't seem to be recognizing it.

// note-controller.js

```
(function(exports) {
  function NoteController(list, listView, tag) {
    this.list = list;
    this.listView = listView;
    this.tag = tag;
  }

  NoteController.prototype.getListView = function() {
    return this.listView.converted;
  };

  NoteController.prototype.outputHTML = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.tag).innerHTML = this.getListView();
  };

  exports.NoteController = NoteController;
})(this);
```

// controller-tests.js

```
describe("#outputHTML", () => {
    var list = { text: "hello this is another note" };
    var listView = {
      converted: "<ul><li><div>hello this is another note</div></li></ul>"
    };
    var mockElement = document.createElement("div");
    mockElement.id = "mock";
    mockElement.innerHTML = "hello";
    var noteController = new NoteController(list, listView, "mock");

    console.log(mockElement); 
 // outputs <div id="mock">hello</div> 

    console.log(document.getElementById("mock"));
 // outputs null

    expect.isEqual(
      "outputs the note as HTML to the page",
      noteController.outputHTML(),
      "<ul><li><div>hello this is another note</div></li></ul>"
    );
  });
```

Do you know why this created tag is not being recognized in the second console.log?

I know this isn't correct yet, but I'm just trying to mock the `document.getElementById` as a step towards the right direction. That being said, do you think this would be an effective strategy towards testing my `outputHTML` function?

Comment: The `mockElement` has not been added to the DOM, so `document.getElementById` won't find it

Comment: Ahh, is there a way of adding it to the DOM?

Comment: The most common way to add an element to the DOM is [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). You'll definitely want to read some tutorials on JavaScript DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Sidney for your suggestions. This is what I came up with to get the passing test;

```
describe("#outputHTML", () => {
    var list = { text: "hello this is another note" };
    var listView = {
      converted: "<ul><li><div>hello this is another note</div></li></ul>"
    };
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
    var mockElement = document.createElement("span");
    mockElement.id = "test";
    body.item(0).appendChild(mockElement);

    var noteController = new NoteController(list, listView, "test");

    expect.isEqual(
      "outputs the note as HTML to the page",
      noteController.outputHTML(),
      "<ul><li><div>hello this is another note</div></li></ul>"
    );

    body.item(0).removeChild(mockElement);
});
```

I managed to create a temporary element tag that my function would recognise to pass the test. After the test I remove it, as it actually applies it to the specrunner page that I created.